# select specific reviewes to apply sentimnet analysis

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I have a dataset that contains the names of some hotels and a review for each hotel, and I want to apply sentiment analysis on only the top ten repeated hotels in the dataset knowing that the dataset contains around 500 hotels
so, how to select the reviews only for the top 10 hotels ??
I tried:

```
DF[DF['hotels']==DF['hotels'].value_counts()[:10]]['review']
```

but it didn't work out, it gave me an error:

> Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any clues??

Comment: Use `isin`: `DF.loc[DF['hotels'].isin(DF['hotels'].value_counts().index[:10]), 'review']`

Answer (score 2):

Rather use `isin` on the index of your `value_counts` output, and `loc` instead of chained slicing to avoid a `SettingWithCopyWarning` if you later use this sliced Series.

```
out = DF.loc[DF['hotels'].isin(DF['hotels'].value_counts().index[:10]), 'review']
```